# Snowflake, Python/Jupyter analysis

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bigdata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am new to Snowflake, and running a query to get a couple of day's data - this returns more than 200 million rows, and take a few days. I tried running the same query in Jupyter - and the kernel restars/dies before the query ends. Even if it got into Jupyter - I doubt I could analyze the data in any reasonable timeline (but maybe using dask?).

I am not really sure where to start - I am trying to check the data for missing values, and my first instinct was to use Jupyter - but I am lost at the moment.

My next idea is to stay within Snowflake - and check the columns there with case statements (e.g. sum(case when column_value = '' then 1 else 0 end) as number_missing_values

Does anyone have any ideas/direction I could try - or know if I'm doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not really the answer you are looking for but

```
sum(case when column_value = '' then 1 else 0 end) as number_missing_values`
```

when you say missing value, this will only find values that are an empty string

this can also be written is a simpler form as:

```
count_if(column_value = '') as number_missing_values
```

The data base already knows how many rows are in a column, and it knows how many null columns there are. If loading data into a table, it might make more sense to not load empty strings, and use null instead then, for not compute cost you can run:

```
count(*) - count(column) as number_empty_values
```

also of note, if you have two tables in snowflake you can compare the via the [MINUS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#minus-except)

aka

```
select * from table_1
minus 
select * from table_2
```

is useful to find missing rows, you do have to do it in both directions.

Then you can [HASH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html) rows, or hash the whole table via [HASH_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash_agg.html)

But normally when looking for missing data, you have an external system, so the driver is 'what can that system handle' and finding common ground.

Also in the past we where search for bugs in our processing that cause duplicate data (where we needed/wanted no duplicates) so then the above, and COUNT DISTINCT like commands come in useful.